# NSLocalized String in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, nslocalizedstring

In swift to create a localized string use `NSLocalizedString(key: , value: , comment:)
But in the older objective C https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstring
There only appears to be key and comment and key appears to act as both the key and the value in the  xliff file.

My question is how do I give a key and value to a nslocalizedstring in objective C?

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for.
1. It gives an error
2. But  more  importantly it appears to require a table for the  key to look  up.  In swift the key value  comment  -> allows me to just enter raw strings and they'll  be organized as such in the  xliff file.   I don't think this link  does  that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) has the correct answer; however, to spell it out directly:

In Swift:

```swift
NSLocalizedString(key, value: value, comment: comment)
```

In Objective C:

```objectivec
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key, nil, NSBundle.mainBundle, value, comment)
```

---

The Objective C version lets you look under the hood to see how it's done. Here is the code for the `NSLocalizedString*` macros in NSBundle.h.

```objectivec
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
        [NSBundle.mainBundle localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
#define NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key, tbl, comment) \
        [NSBundle.mainBundle localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:(tbl)]
#define NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, tbl, bundle, comment) \
        [bundle localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:(tbl)]
#define NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(key, tbl, bundle, val, comment) \
        [bundle localizedStringForKey:(key) value:(val) table:(tbl)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You’re looking at a reduced form of the macro. The full form is called saying

```
NSString * NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(
  NSString *key,
  NSString *tableName,
  NSBundle *bundle,
  NSString *value,
  NSString *comment
)
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstringwithdefaultvalue

Just set the stuff you don’t care about at nil.